# Create Array of Labels

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm really hoping to find some way to either create an Array of Label() or to create a Label variable with a constructed name using a string. Unfortunately after searching I'm afraid it won't be possible so I'm looking for alternatives as well.

I have a List of Strings, and I would like to create a Label for each one, inside of a Form using System.Windows.Forms. I am hoping to avoid having one large label holding all of the text, or needing to create a large number of predefined labels, as the number of Strings my list contains will vary from 3 or 4 to 30 or higher.

After some trial and error I have managed to get it not crashing, and the information I am setting to the Label is setting correctly, but becomes nothing outside of the For Loop.

```
Sub CheckResult(ByRef strList As List(Of String))
        Dim LineCount As Integer = strList.Count
        Dim Line As String
        With CheckForm
            .size = New System.Drawing.Size(340, (LineCount * 20) + 40 )
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            .MaximizeBox = False
            .MinimizeBox = False
            .Text = CheckType
        End With
        
        Dim CheckTextLabel(0 To LineCount - 1) As Label
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each Line In strList
            Line = strList(i)
            CheckTextLabel(i) = New Label()
            With CheckTextLabel(i)
                .Text = Line
                .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(320, 20)
                .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + (LineCount * 20))
                '.Font = MidFont
            End With
            CheckForm.Controls.Add(CheckTextLabel(i))
            'Location 1
            i += 1
        Next
    'Location 2
    ...
```

When I check the value of CheckTextLabel(i).Text at Location 1, I get the expected value.
If I check the value of CheckTextLabel(1) or any other value for i at Location 2, it returns a blank result.
Please let me know if there is a way to do this, and if as I fear there is not, I'll accept alternatives

Comment: Firstly, why use a `For Each` loop and then keep a separate variable as a counter? Why not just use a `For` loop, which has a counter built in? You're not even using the loop control variable properly inside the loop anyway. Also, surely you should be using `i` when specifying the `Location` rather than `LineCount`.

Comment: Why is the method parameter declared `ByRef`? Are you assigning a new object to the parameter inside the method and want that reflected in the original variable? That is the only reason to declare that parameter `ByRef` so if you don't want that, don't do that.

Comment: As for the issue, what you describe is simply not possible. Your code could be simplified quite a bit but, even as it is, that array will still be populated with distinct `Labels` with distinct text. I just tested your code, with a few modifications required to make it run (in future, take heed of [this]()), and I was able to get the expected value of `CheckTextLabel(1).Text` after that loop. I don;t know what you're doing wrong but the problem you're reporting doesn't exist.

Comment: Might I suggest you take a bit of time and look at the TableLayoutControl. or FlowLayoutControl.  Makes positioning runtime controls much simpler

Comment: Neglected to provide the link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in my previous comment.